# Unknown exception Mass email constructor

Tags: email, apex-email-service, massemailmessage, mass-email

I am trying to send an email with apex controller and VF interface.
But when I send the message, I have an error :

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, null: [] Error is in expression
>   '{!sendPrivate}' in component  in page sendemail:
>   Class.sendEmail.sendPrivate: line 82, column 1
>
> Class.sendEmail.sendPrivate: line 82, column 1

This is a part of my apex controller :

```
public class sendEmail {
public String subject { get; set; }
public String body { get; set; }
public blob docBody { get; set; }
public String docName { get; set; }
public List < Membres__c > membersP { get; set; }
public List < Membres__c > membersC { get; set; }
public List < Membres__c > membersCorp { get; set; }
public List < Id > idP { get; set; }
public List < Id > idC { get; set; }
public List < Id > idCorp { get; set; }

// Create a constructor that populates the Account object
public sendEmail() {

    List < Id > idP = new List < Id >();
    List < Id > idC = new List < Id >();
    List < Id > idCorp = new List < Id >();

    membersP = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '012240000002GRv' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];
    membersC = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '012240000002GSt' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];
    membersCorp = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '01I24000001M8lz' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];

        idP.add('0032400000gKaFB');
    for (Membres__c m : membersP) {
        idP.add(m.Contact__c);
    }
    for (Membres__c m : membersC) {
        idC.add(m.Contact__c);
    }
    for (Membres__c m : membersCorp) {
        idCorp.add(m.Contact__c);
    }
}

public List < Membres__c > getMembresP() {
    return membersP;
}

public List < Membres__c > getMembresC() {
    return membersC;
}

public List < Membres__c > getMembresCorp() {
    return membersCorp;
}

// Partie Private
public PageReference sendPrivate() {

    // Création de l'email
    Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

    // Create the email attachment
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName( docName );
    efa.setBody( docBody );

    // Gestion des paramètres généraux
    email.setTargetObjectIds( idP );
    email.setWhatIds( idP );
    email.setSubject( subject );
    email.setSenderDisplayName('URB-BKV');
    email.setTemplateID('00X24000000Mxfa');
    //email.setDescription( body );

    // Create email on contact
    email.setSaveAsActivity(true);

    // Attach document
    //email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    // Send Email
    //Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
    //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { email });
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { email });

    return null;
}
```

I do not have any Idea of the problem.
The single email method works fine, but when i try the mass email constructor...
Nothing
Thanks for your help

Max

Comment: I think you should first streamlining your SOQL queries. Those three queries could be rebuilt on only one. Check this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Combine_Queries_for_Efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring same list in class level and constructor. So the scope of values added to the list will be within constructor. `sendPrivate()` is accessing values in `idP` list which is declared in class level which does not have any values. Ideally you should declare lists in class level and initialise in constructor. Try code below.

```
public class sendEmail {
    public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public blob docBody { get; set; }
    public String docName { get; set; }
    public List < Membres__c > membersP { get; set; }
    public List < Membres__c > membersC { get; set; }
    public List < Membres__c > membersCorp { get; set; }
    public List < Id > idP { get; set; }
    public List < Id > idC { get; set; }
    public List < Id > idCorp { get; set; }

    // Create a constructor that populates the Account object
    public sendEmail() {

        idP = new List < Id >();
        idC = new List < Id >();
        idCorp = new List < Id >();

        membersP = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '012240000002GRv' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];
        membersC = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '012240000002GSt' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];
        membersCorp = [select Id, Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email FROM Membres__c where RecordTypeId =: '01I24000001M8lz' AND Contact__r.Email != null LIMIT 1];

        idP.add('0032400000gKaFB');
        for (Membres__c m : membersP) {
            idP.add(m.Contact__c);
        }
        for (Membres__c m : membersC) {
            idC.add(m.Contact__c);
        }
        for (Membres__c m : membersCorp) {
            idCorp.add(m.Contact__c);
        }
    }

    public List < Membres__c > getMembresP() {
        return membersP;
    }

    public List < Membres__c > getMembresC() {
        return membersC;
    }

    public List < Membres__c > getMembresCorp() {
        return membersCorp;
    }

    // Partie Private
    public PageReference sendPrivate() {

        // Création de l'email
        Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName( docName );
        efa.setBody( docBody );

        // Gestion des paramètres généraux
        email.setTargetObjectIds( idP );
        email.setWhatIds( idP );
        email.setSubject( subject );
        email.setSenderDisplayName('URB-BKV');
        email.setTemplateID('00X24000000Mxfa');
        //email.setDescription( body );

        // Create email on contact
        email.setSaveAsActivity(true);

        // Attach document
        //email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

        // Send Email
        //Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
        //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { email });
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { email });

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Points to note:**

- Declare variables in class level if same variables are used in different methods.
- Avoid hard coded ids
- Minimal number of SOQL. If you are querying same object the best practise is to have one soql.

Comment: Hi Reshma,

Thanks, it works.
The hard coded IDs was to test it on one specific email.
I will delete it.

I can have one SOQL, and I will, thanks for advices.
I don't know what I did with this lists...

I have additional questions just to be sure.
We have to use template for mass email ? Could we not just use a VF page with rich text to set the body ? (Maybe I have to create/edit a template with VF to use it...)
And can we not log activities on Contact with standard method ?
And the last question : Can I add an attachment in mass email ?

Thanks again for your advices.

Comment: @Max Glad to help you. Can you post your new queries as new question.